# Creating a test Django environment from the existing production Django project

Tags: python, django, testing, django-templates

I've developed a Django project which is in production and used by a small team daily.
Now I want to make some changes in UI, since there is no test environment, I tried creating a similar base and home page with different names for testing in production environment but it is throwing error in ajax url resolving, I don't want to create another set of ajax url for testing.
Is there any better way to create a test environment to test the UI changes and copy the html and java script alone?
(it is a single developer project I use github only when I push any big change)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the application separately somewhere else for the test environment or run it on localhost.